# Smooth only top angles and imageview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rounded-corners, cornerradius

I'm trying to round only the top top corners (TopLeft and TopRight) of a view and imageview. With the code below I was able to round up only the left corner (although there is also specified TopRight). Maybe he doesn't see the constraint placed on the storyboard.

How do I fix?

Thank you.

```
let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
        rectShape.bounds = self.CopertinaImage1.frame
        rectShape.position = self.CopertinaImage1.center
        rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.CopertinaImage1.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath

        self.CopertinaImage1.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        self.CopertinaImage1.layer.mask = rectShape
```

The right corner is always the same: 
[image]
**Edit:**

I've tried placing the following code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() { 
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() 
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer() 
    rectShape.bounds = self.CopertinaImage1.frame 
    rectShape.position = self.CopertinaImage1.center 
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.CopertinaImage1.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath 
    self.CopertinaImage1.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor 
    self.CopertinaImage1.layer.mask = rectShape
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: If yore using auto layout you need to move your code to after the auto layout engine has finished setting your view's frames. Likely `viewDidLayoutSubviews` if you're doing this in a `UIViewController`

Comment: tried but it doesn't work

I entered under the viewDidLoad

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = self.CopertinaImage1.frame
    rectShape.position = self.CopertinaImage1.center
    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.CopertinaImage1.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath

    self.CopertinaImage1.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    self.CopertinaImage1.layer.mask = rectShape

Comment: Is the view you're trying to mask in a `UITableViewCell` subclass? If so, the code should be in the `layoutSubviews` of it. Also `rectShape.bounds = self.CopertinaImage1.frame` and `rectShape.position = self.CopertinaImage1.center` seems wrong to me. I would try replacing them with `rectShape.frame = self.CopertinaImage1.bounds`

Comment: No @beyowulf. I tried to delete rectShape.bounds = self.CopertinaImage1.frame and rectShape.position = self.CopertinaImage1.center by putting in place rectShape.frame = self.CopertinaImage1.bounds but it doesn't work. :(

Comment: It's not a table view. In a View Controller I inserted a View with inside (in the middle) an ImageView.

Comment: Then `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the right place for this kind of code. What constraints does the `UIImageView` have on it? Perhaps it's frame is wider than it's superview's, which is being masked to bounds, making the right rounded corner not show up?

Comment: See this image @beyowulf -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22334399/Schermata%202016-06-09%20alle%2021.24.36.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the code you've posted. For whatever reason when I enter your constraints and recreate your view hierarch, the auto layout engine does not call `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after it does it's second pass. I could force it to but calling `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` from `viewWillAppear`. For example:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
        rectShape.frame = self.imageView.bounds
        rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.imageView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).CGPath
        self.imageView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        self.imageView.layer.mask = rectShape
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Results in:

[image]

With both corners rounded.

I would say a better, more elegant solution that avoids this auto layout glitch is to just set the corner radius of the image view container, as it seems like that what you're doing anyways. For example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imageContainerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        self.imageContainerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
```

You can also do this from `viewDidLoad` because it doesn't depend on any of your views' frames being set.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code in a playground. Worked fine for me. Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem.

[image]

Comment: Same here.  Worked in playground.  Is it possible the top right is getting clipped by some container view?

Comment: I see the right corner is always the same. Look here -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22334399/Schermata%202016-06-09%20alle%2012.15.50.png